# No visible @interface declares the selector

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `SSLYFoodDetailViewController.h` whose contents are

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SSLYFoodDetailViewController : UIViewController

@property(nonatomic, weak) NSString *foodItem;
@property(nonatomic, weak) NSString *restaurantName;

- (void) setFoodItem:(NSString *)foodItem;
- (void) setRestaurantName:(NSString *)restaurantName;

@end
```

In another file `SSLYTableViewController.m` inside the `prepareForSegue` method, I try to do the following -

```
SSLYFoodDetailViewController *sslyFoodDetailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
[sslyFoodDetailViewController setFoodItem:@"Pasta"];
```

XCode is giving me an error that there is `No visible @interface for 'SSLYFoodDetailViewController' declares the selector 'setFoodItem'`.

At the top of the `SSLYTableViewController.m`, I have the import statement -

```
#import "SSLYFoodDetailViewController.h"
```

What is it that I am missing?

Comment: That error message implies that somewhere you are calling `setFoodItem` without a parameter.

Comment: 1. You don't need to declare the setters: 
- (void) setFoodItem:(NSString *)foodItem;
- (void) setRestaurantName:(NSString *)restaurantName;
2. XCode is a nasty thing sometimes. Try clean and build or even delete derived data and/or quit XCode and restart.
BTW: Are you sure you want the properties to be referenced weak?

Comment: Why would you declare these properties `weak`? The best practice for `NSString` properties is to declare them `(nonatomic, copy)`.

Comment: Ok will read about using `(nonatomic, copy)` - I am very new to Objective-C and don't know a lot of stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That doesn't make any sense, except that `setFoodItem:` is implied by the foodItem `@property` declaration.

Try removing the declarations for `setFoodItem:` and `setRestaurantName:` in your header - that definitely won't hurt anything because they're redundant.

If that doesn't work, try the property accessor notation:

```
sslyFoodDetailViewController.foodItem = @"Pasta";
```

Also of note, you're probably getting a warning on the line:

```
SSLYFoodDetailViewController *sslyFoodDetailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
```

You should add an explicit cast in that line, as follows:

```
SSLYFoodDetailViewController *sslyFoodDetailViewController = (SSLYFoodDetailViewController *) [segue destinationViewController];
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but that didn't work either. Then I removed the `SSLYFoodDetailViewController` (both `.h` and `.m` files) and created them again. It worked - maybe XCode was behaving. I was aware that I do not need to explicitly declare the setter methods and now it works with that.

Comment: @Siddharth when I am sure I'm doing everything right, I usually try a Project > Clean.